# What is the difference between "multinomial" and "polytomous"?

Tags: econometrics, multinomial-distribution, discrete-data

I would like to know the difference a multinomial model and a polytomous model. Both a multinomial model, for example multinomial logit / probit model, and a polytomous model are used for estimation of quantitative data. But, a polytomous model is seldom used. I think that the difference is　whether to estimate parameters for every category. So, in polytomous model, the parameters of each category is the same. Is it correct?

Moreover, I would be interested in understanding the estimation method for the polytomous model. If someone understands it, I would appreciate it someone could point that out to me.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Pavel. I edited the sentence in your 2nd paragraph based on what I think you are asking. Please make sure that it says what you want it to. Also note that StackExchange sites automatically attach your username, flair, & a link to your userpage to your posts; thus, we ask that you don't sign your posts.

Comment: Statistics is not as unified as other disciplines: often different words are used for the same thing and the same word for different things. I suspect that @FrankHarrell is right, but it really depends on the exact context in which you found these words. So can you tell us where you found references to these models and why you think that they are different?

Comment: Thank you very much for your commnents, Maarten-san.
I found a polytomous model in Ref. for the first time. The coefficients of the multinomial model is often expressed as $\beta_j$. So, the coefficients of the multinomial model is estimated for every category, except reference category in a multinomial logit model. But, the coefficients of the polytomous model in the Ref. is $\beta_0$. So, the coefficients is the same.


Ref.: Kelejian and Prucha, 2001([pdf](http://econweb.umd.edu/~prucha/Papers/JE104%282001%29.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

The two terms refer to the same model or type of $Y$.

Comment: Would you consider ordinal data to be polytomous?

Comment: @Momo, you are right at your comment. "tomous" ("anatomy") is "cut", so ordinal scale is polytomous, because it is categorical. Multinomial is a nominal scale - with multiple unordered categories. Polytomous is any categorical scale with more than 2 categories, so it is opposed to "dichotomous".

Comment: This is my understanding as well, at least how its used in psychometrics. I'd say multinomial data are a subset of polytomous data but I'd also appreciate to know how Frank Harrell sees it.

Comment: I see multinomial as exactly equal to polytomous except "polytomous" because of "to cut" has a subtle implication that $Y$ might have originally been more finely grained and may have been cut (unnecessarily) into courser intervals.  You could say that ordinal $Y$ is also polytomous-multinomial but that would not have complete specificity.